# Compare column value in foldleft

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to summarise columns in a DataFrame into a new column which will be added to the dataframe itself.

This is the DataFrame

```
val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("r1", 1, 1),
  ("r2", 6, 4),
  ("r3", 4, 1),
  ("r4", 1, 2)
)).toDF("ID", "a", "b")
```

and I simply would like to add a column "ones" having the count of ones in "a" and "b".

This is the Scala code I came up with, unfortunately it returns 0 for any row and cannot get it working. Any help appreciated!

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, col}

val columns = Seq("a", "b").map(col _)

def countOnes(cols: Column*) = cols.foldLeft(lit(0)){
  (cnt, current) => 
    if (current == 1) 
      cnt + 1
    else
      cnt
}

val output = input.withColumn("ones", countOnes(columns: _*))
output.show
```

Expected result is:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   2|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   1|
| r4|  1|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to construct the column expression that count the number of ones per row, then create the new column using `withColumn` function:

```
val ones = Seq("a", "b").map(x => when(col(x) === 1, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _)

input.withColumn("ones", ones).show
+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   2|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   1|
| r4|  1|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Or if using `foldLeft`, you need `when.otherwise` instead of `if/else` for column operation:

```
def countOnes(cols: Column*) = cols.foldLeft(lit(0)){
    (cnt, current) => when(current === 1, cnt + 1).otherwise(cnt)
}

val output = input.withColumn("ones", countOnes(columns: _*))

output.show
+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   2|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   1|
| r4|  1|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: thanks for it and for the prompt reply. I see there is a a bit of knowledge there which I miss. Probably around spark sql and DataFrames. Can you suggest a good reading - book, api doc, online stuff - I can look at so to scale up my skills in here?

Comment: The [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/index.html) is pretty useful, where you can find both programming guide and API links by clicking the *API docs* tab at the top. The [spark sql functions (scala)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) is very useful as well.

Comment: Impressed with this. Also cannot find right docs, but getting there!